# How to autoselect previously uploaded file in html file type element when the file selection window is cancelled?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I have following html and javascript codes.

```js
function run() {
  alert(document.getElementById("file").value);
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="run()">
```

Here, when user clicks the "browse" button and selects a file, the javascript alerts out the file selected by the user. The issue is, after selecting a file when the user again clicks the "browse" button but clicks the cancel now without making any selection, the javascript code alerts nothing. I mean even though user cancels the window the javascript should still be alerting out the previously selected file.

And I get this issue only on chrome, not in firefox or IE. The code is very basic so the code is not the problem i guess. I think it is a cross browser problem. Any idea ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That might be for security reason, but Chrome restore the value to nothing when the user click on cancel. Probably because if the user clicked again the input, it means their didn't want to send this file.

Comment: Do I have any way around, to get what i need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code for chrome browser.

```js
var prev;
$("input[type=file]").bind("click", function() {
    prev=$(this).val();
});
$("input[type=file]").bind("change", function() {
    var selected_file_name = $(this).val();
    if ( selected_file_name.length > 0 ) {
        /* Some file selected */
      alert("Selected File Name : "+ selected_file_name);
      
    }
    else {
        /* No file selected or cancel/close
           dialog button clicked */
        /* If user has select a file before,
           when they submit, it will treated as
           no file selected */
      alert("Previously selected File Name : "+ prev);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file">
```